# Sql Server 2005 Replication

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

I am developing a web portal in Asp.Net. Primary target users will be of India Only. But in future I may target overseas users also. I want to know if I should use Sql Server Replication or not. Should I concern about "Replication" at initial stage or can I use it at later stages. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think replication means what you think it means. Replication is a means of synchronizing multiple databases with data and it is most useful where databases need to be disconnected at times.

I don't think you need to be concerned about replication if you are developing a web app. If you will have multiple sites in the future, you can still have a single database hosted separately from any of the sites that all the localized sites reference and update independently.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you will have multiple databases to be consolidated into a central db, **NO**, dont worry about it.

It will bring a whole world of hurt.

Comment: Thanks, But In future I will have Multiple databases.